# Custom URI schemes in Windows

Tags: windows, uri

I know Windows (at least prior to Windows 10) allowed you to register a handler for a custom URI protocol. But is there a way to register an application to handle an existing URI protocol conforming to a particular format as you can in Android. Specifically, I want `https` URLs with a particular domain to be handled by the app rather than the default browser.

Comment: no. windows' file handling capabilities are NOT that fine grained. you'd need to have some other app that handles all urls itself, and then decides what browser/app to file up based on the url.

Comment: That's disappointing but I'll still accept it as an answer if you make it one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not really possible to do this on Windows. The way protocols are launched on Windows is basically unchanged from Windows 95.

It could sort of work in theory if you set your verb as the default (in a list of default verbs which is rare in itself) and then filtered yourself out using a [`AppliesTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx) value if the "path" does not contain your domain. I have never tested but I don't believe `AppliesTo` is parsed for protocol handlers, only for file-types. And even if it was parsed it would be very fragile; if the user changes the default browser your registration would be lost.